# Странные дела с Самбой

Tags: samba, kubuntu

Самба на Кубунте 14.04 (и на всех раньше было). Отчего-то доступ возникает только после перезапуска smbd командой `sudo service smbd restart` из терминала. Ну, в общем-то это неплохо, безопасность выше. НО ПОЧЕМУ??? Кто-нибудь может прояснить?

Answer (score 1):

Перечитывает файлы настройки + пинаете демона. Не подвисает ли он? Может это подскажет что:
[Зависание (DoS) Samba при открытии в Netbeans большого проекта](http://mexxval.blogspot.ru/2013/04/dos-samba-netbeans.html) 
[Samba. Поиск и устранение неисправностей в работе системы](http://habrahabr.ru/post/173127/)
[Samba зависает если нет инета](http://forum.lissyara.su/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22006)
Ну и гугл, конечно, в помощь
 [Тема: Шара видна только после перезапуска Samba](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=50430.0) - вот еще нарыл. кажется это то что нужно

Кстати, Антон, насколько понимаю сисадминишь? Так что с праздником!

Comment: Спасибо за поздравление! И Вас туда же! :) И - огромное спасибо за последнюю ссылочку - дело было именно в этом.